# logical problem (how long did you walk?)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

My wife is very kind, she always picks me up at work by car and drives me home. Today, I finished at work 30 minutes earlier! So I decided to walk home... on the way I met my wife. She was on her way to pick me up, so I sat in the car and she drove me home. Today I was home 10 minutes earlier than usual.

How long did I walk?

Does anyone know how to solve it using maths and not just guessing? :)

Comment: Do you need to make it clearer or something?  Idk.

Comment: I would like to know the answer and how to get to the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say the drive to work reliably takes $d$ minutes in each direction, and let's imagine that your wife, punctual soul, always turns up exactly as you finish work.

So normally you get home $d$ minutes after finishing time $f$, that is $f+d$,  with your wife having left to pick you at $f-d$,  driving for $2d$ minutes.

But this time, you started walking at $f-30$, and after leaving at $f-d$, your wife got home at $f+d-10$ and thus she only drove for $2d-10$ minutes - which must be $(d-5)$ minutes out and $(d-5)$ minutes back.

And that means - as others have already mentioned - that she picked you up $5$ minutes earlier than usual, that is at $(f-d)+(d-5) = f-5$.

So you were walking from $f-30$ to $f-5$; that is, $25$ minutes.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the help. I was very curious :)

Comment: I found this problem very funny :P it's kind of different than the typical problems.. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  She drove 5 minutes less in each direction than usual.

Comment: I find this problem very funny.. I can't even set up a system of equations :S I completely understand your hint but how do I proceed?

Comment: Joffan did it in detail.